# jquery if current disable click

Tags: jquery

Please take a look and click on the "package 2" rectangle and see the animation I'm trying to create, it's working fine but if you'll click again the animation will continue and I would like to create something like: 
If it's on the current one, the click option will be disabled

code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#tab2').click(function(){
        $('.current').animate({ left: "+=208" });
    }); 

});
```

Full Code:
http://jsfiddle.net/13sh602y/

Comment: You can just add a class to what's clicked and check for it to determine to execute the code or not, then remove the class when another one is clicked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you rather want a generic function ?

check this out

added a classname to the tabs and animate the .current to the offset.left of current clicked tab

```
<div class="current">V</div>
<ul>
    <li class="tabb" id="tab1">package1</li>
    <li class="tabb" id="tab2">package2</li>
    <li class="tabb" id="tab3">package3</li>
</ul>
```

-

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.tabb').click(function(){
        $('.current').stop(true,false)
        $('.current').animate({ left: $(this).offset().left });
    }); 

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/13sh602y/1/

Comment: added  `$('.current').stop(true,false)` so you have no weird laggy behaviour if you click several tabs in short time